# C# , How to have code wait for user input before moving on to do Math

Tags: c#

Hi I am in the process of Learning C#, trying to write a short Console Program that will take a users age and convert it into dog years.

The issue I am having is it doesn't wait for the user input, so it assigns 0 as the value then returns 0 (because 0*7 = 0 ) for dog Age

How do I get the code to stop running until the user enters a value

My code :

```
Console.WriteLine("what is your age?");
string humanAge = Console.ReadLine();
int dogAge = Convert.ToInt32(humanAge) * 7;

Console.WriteLine(dogAge);
```

Comment: That code works. How/Where are you trying to run this where you're not getting it to wait for the user input?

Comment: @mariocatch I am running it inside of the built in console for Code Academy

Comment: Code Academy may not wait for user input, and might skip over those. I don't know for sure, just my assumption. Also, your question states "trying to write a short Console Program", but you're trying to run it in a browser learning app it sounds like... which may be why you're getting downvoted by others.

Comment: Maybe there is a "program input" in the interface like this: https://www.mycompiler.io/view/8x8AJ2XRwXT

Comment: Yeah I think your write I , opened up Visual Studio and ran the code , added a Console.ReadLine() at the end and everything works


appreciate your help I was under the impression it takes input before running it because in some of the modules it does; it must only wait on certain assignments

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with the Code Academy App not the code as mariocatch stated ; closing the question